# Json date string conversion in android

Tags: android, datetime

How can I convert this type of date

`2016-05-30T15:47:20.833`

into this format

`Jan 1, 2016 10:15:55 AM`

I got the code how to convert this type of json date `"\"\\/Date(1335205592410)\\/\""` into others date format in web.

I have stuck with my problem. can anybody help me to find out the proper solution ?

Comment: Assuming same timezone here?

Comment: just time format will be changed. i got my solution. thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This it may be help to you

```
SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"); 
SimpleDateFormat destFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss a"); //here 'a' for AM/PM


Date date = null;
    try {
        date = sourceFormat.parse("2016-05-30T15:47:20.833");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
String formattedDate = destFormat.format(date);  

Toast.makeText(this, formattedDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: @victorbijoy always wlc